# My CSV data seems fine, however when I plot my graph, the data doesn't seem right

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I imported CSV file and the data seems right. However, when i plot the graph using matplotlib, the data seems clustered on the Y-axis. Likewise, the data doesn't seem right. At 2019, the price of this currency should rise, and not decline.

I have tried shifting the x-axis, changing the range of y-axis but it still doesn't work.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

plt.plot(XAU_USD.Date,XAU_USD.Price) 

plt.title('Daily XAU/USD Price',color='red')

plt.xticks(Yield_Curve.Date[::107])

plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

plt.show()
```

Is there a way for me to fix the data within Jupiter Notebook?

This is the output of the graph

[image]

This is the CSV file imported into my py[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1iZq.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: `I imported CSV file` -What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Y data is not numeric.

Try `plt.plot(XAU_USD.Date,XAU_USD.Price.values.astype(float))`

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-94c8f2b342c2> in <module>
      2 plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
      3 #Plotting Adjusted Closing Price in and changing the label name
----> 4 plt.plot(XAU_USD.Date,XAU_USD.Price.values.astype(float))
      5 #Plotting title
      6 plt.title('Daily XAU/USD Price',color='red')

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,538.76'

<Figure size 1440x576 with 0 Axes>

Comment: You see some of the values are in this broken format, that's why Pandas loaded them as object (string). Check the `pd.to_numeric` with `errors=coerce`

Answer (score 0):

I truly appreciate your feedbacks to resolve my questions. So, the solution to this is simple. I went to amend the CSV files, I changed the prices into 'number'. This will remove the commas. (eg. 1,234.45 to 1234.45) After converting to an int. The program is able to take in the values and plot the graph from there. [This is the new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MimUm.png)